# I want to execute a report subscription by clicking on a field

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report on the SQL Server Report Service that lists all reports and their corresponding subscriptions.

```
[report name] [subscription description] [run]
```

I have added a column called `[run]` that contains an image. I want to make it so that if the user clicks on the `[run]` image/cell, it executes the corresponding subscription.

Is this possible?

I've looked at the image action, but it only seems to allow execution of reports (not subscriptions) or URLs.

Comment: You may be able to leverage the intrinsic way of how ReportServer executes the subscription via the SQL Server Agent Jobs through your own approach but may not be exposed natively. By reviewing the latest subscription from our SQL server, I see that the jobs just execute the following statement, `exec [Your_RS_Database].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='<SubscriptionID>'`

Comment: I don't know how to invoke SQL when clicking on a cell.

Comment: You cannot invoke SQL directly when clicking on a cell from a report but there are other alternatives (may not be the best approaches) to invoke a report. Were you looking for the report to be executed and renderable on the click, or just executed?

Comment: I just want the subscription to be executed.

Comment: An option would be to setup a web-service that accepts a `SubscriptionID` parameter and executes the above SQL line of code. With it being a web-service, it will accommodate the options available to you when clicking a table cell (ie, through the `Go to URL` Action on a table cell -- http://whatever_website/yourService?SID=<SubscriptionID>)

Comment: you can have the action directed to a web page that runs the sql mention by @AnthonyForloney.

Comment: The workaround I used was to create a separate report called SubscriptionRunner which executed Anthony's SQL. I then set the Action property in original report to run SubscriptionRunner. This has the side effect of opening SubscriptionRunner (which I would prefer to avoid) but it will do for now.

Comment: @JinKim For readability purposes, would you mind providing the above as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I used was to create a separate report called SubscriptionRunner which accepts one parameter (the subscription id) and executes that subscription using the following SQL (provided by Anthony Forloney):

```
EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData=<SubscriptionID>
```

I then set the Action property of the cell in the original report to Run the SubscriptionRunner report.

This has the side effect of opening SubscriptionRunner (which I would prefer to avoid) but it will do for now.